# IdentityServer URL Rewrite Module Invalid Verb

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, self-hosting, identityserver3

I hope your're doing well.

My issue is, I have two application one of them is Identityserver which is selft hosted, and the other one is a basic application on MVC installed on IIS 8.5 and this one use URL ReWrite,

So, first I installed my identityserver and everything was to be Ok, I could log in and manage my service successfylly, but when I installed the URL Rewrite Module for my second application the identityserver gave this error

> Bad Request - Invalid Verb
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.

After that I unistalled the Url rewrite module to ensure about that and my identityserver start to operate normally.

So my question is, How to configure my self hosted IdentityServer to work along with Url Rewrite Module?

**UPDATE**

I tried to make some extra configurations on my identityserver, and when I leave pass the time my server tried to end sessions with this URL

```
http://localhost/core/connect/endsession?post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:1111/&id_token_hint=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImRNdXRmLUlTcERrTzVrcHBVUFRhWnFQZXFBZyIsImtpZCI6ImRNdXRmLUlTcERrTzVrcHBVUFRhWnFQZXFBZyJ9.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.bDPTLRLBcVCBFu2xG5tgnoIM1qIUbJu_68inRuYYqh8cjpkBVK7ZUsh-tFEWIidpIatEQWPMGE3clxdsjgNXQFp_hpgLCo6TqGmIeLoOPP8cIPOUQcMqoPXHpdii8QFW8uhYm2j7Yi90ZJicgFISTKPi8HHwa8vyvFfTz6p6v-I6tdtxNMOy6FIr-BpNmODk7I6S5UwlJdiEa1m_GRo1YgFS8WgCKCi0p0TIF6QKT7FbaU4D2pu9wq0vLRaK8yQg8_1m2e01DPTKsi-OoAlfJqC3PiGi8cgst69sPUC9Lrb3lEC92m9RlS-4GcWhU03qwrGj6VWeJp3fyLAMh12CJquYYAyzannwuAgBx51mVQympmPhjXg2ItsKJb4GTvqlGVUIFCMjJqKqRnU7PGt2eTEDrID52kKsHH3mknWQTZOmr0rJmuG3ZyuJsCPk9hwmJuYED0RX76liyZLkW6jwx3PgDRsA3es7OMUoWIjpjPz9yhtJ79lD3w6L8Y-BO3M1JuFdFk4wYsANOw6Qr5x6RsePJqUqRkVXHFfv4bA1aA4RATHCvjcQ8qOunUZXgxIOXco2CtZZK6yRa_6uXaNkkqdR6tiej0WNDo52vjCU_JJI3Yt5sHXfnIQbNXFDeXcOsekb_ACYFRPoi7FVdZrUQ9KQx5aBqst9KbRenJAIa1E
```

and there's where the problem is, but I don't know why because before install URL Rewrite Module my identityserver was working normally

**UPDATE 2**

I reproduced the exact error, I using pos logout redirect with the id_token_hint, so when the token expires because of its datetime comes this erros about Bad Request - Invalid Verb,

The problem doesn't seen to be with the url rewriting module.

How can solve this problem?

Thanks for you help in advanced.

Best regards!.

Comment: What are you rewriting about the URL?

Comment: on my identityserver?  I'm not rewriting anything, in fact, My identityserver is selft hosted with windows service, I realized the are not all urls from identityserver that seens to have the problem,

but for example in this url i'm having the Bad Request - Invalid Verb
...core/connect/endsession?post_logout_redirect_uri=myurl&id_token_hint=mytoken

all the other uris seens to be OK
thank for you're reply @BrockAllen

Comment: Still not sure what the issue is -- you will have to do some more debugging.